# How to use the C library "_int128_t.h" in Cython

Tags: cython, int128

In the file .py I use the function:

```
def xor(block: int, key: int) -> int:
    return block ^ key
```

To which 128-bit numbers are transmitted.

I want to replace it with a function implemented in Cython. But I can't figure out how to use 128-bit numbers there

I wrote the code:

.pyx

```
import cython

cdef extern from *:
    ctypedef int int128 "__int128_t"

cpdef int128 xor(int128 block, int128 key):
    return block ^ key
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules=cythonize('C_code.pyx', language_level="3"))
```

however, errors occur during compilation.

Comment: Which errors do you get exactly? When I try your code (with Cython-0.29.34 and and x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc 11.3.0 as C compiler) the code compiles and runs without problems.

Comment: indeed, using the gcc compiler, it was possible to compile the file, however, after importing this function into a file.py and an attempt to pass a 128-bit number to it, an error occurs: cpdef int128 xor(int128 block, int128 key): Overflow error: int is too big to convert @Marijn